# Xamarin iOS Google Maps SDK - Exception with mapView.AddObserver()

Tags: c#, ios, google-maps, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to get the current position of the device using Google Maps SDK in Xamarin.iOS, I got the following code but I'm getting an exception.

I've imported the Google Maps SDK for iOS in Xamarin

```
using Google.Maps;
```

This is my code:

```
MapView gmapView;
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    CameraPosition camera = CameraPosition.FromCamera (latitude: 40.7056308, 
            longitude: -73.9780035, 
            zoom: 13);
    mapView = MapView.FromCamera (new RectangleF(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Bottom - 50), camera);
    mapView.Settings.CompassButton = true;
    mapView.Settings.MyLocationButton = true;

    // Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
    mapView.AddObserver (this, new NSString ("myLocation"), NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);

    // More code ...
    // ...

    // Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.
    InvokeOnMainThread (()=> mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true);
}
```

Then I define the method that should be called when the position of the user changes:

```
public override void ObserveValue (NSString keyPath, NSObject ofObject, NSDictionary change, IntPtr context)
{
    if (!firstLocationUpdate) {
        // If the first location update has not yet been recieved, then jump to that
        // location.
        firstLocationUpdate = true; 
        var location = change.ObjectForKey (NSValue.ChangeNewKey) as CLLocation;
        mapView.Camera = CameraPosition.FromCamera (location.Coordinate, 14);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception and have been stuck with this for a while with no luck :/

```
MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: <MapViewController: 0x1b6648c0>: An -   observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to move this line

```
mapView.AddObserver (this, new NSString ("myLocation"), NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Inside the InvokeOnMainThread, like this:

```
InvokeOnMainThread (()=> { 
    mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true;
    mapView.AddObserver (this, new NSString ("myLocation"), NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem, was trying everything but nothing helped. Mayber there is some bug in Xamarin's Google Maps library.

Finally I've rewritten the `observer` to `timer`. It's ugly but it's working for now.

```
NSRunLoop.Main.AddTimer (NSTimer.CreateRepeatingTimer (0.2d, (timer) => {
    var location = mapView.MyLocation;

    if (location == null) {
        return;
    } else {
        timer.Invalidate ();
    }

    //do what you need with current location

}), NSRunLoopMode.Default);
```